# I want to Hide CSS ID for specific user roles

Tags: css

I want to Hide CSS .edit-post-meta-boxes-area for specific user role (rc_author) in Post Editor.

Please repair my code

```
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_css_of_current_specific_user_role');
    function add_css_of_current_specific_user_role()
    { 
        /*Check Current User is Login*/
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
        {  
           $user = wp_get_current_user();
           /*Check Current User Role*/
           if (in_array('rc_author', $user->roles)) { ?>
    
                <style>
                .edit-post-meta-boxes-area {display: none;}
                </style>
    
        <?php } 
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: where have you placed this code? Does the CSS get added to the page? How are you testing this code? Note that `wp_head` is a frontend action not an admin area action

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `wp_head` is called only on the frontend. You should use `admin_head` if you want to print something in the admin.